# Agregar botón de Skype en mi web

Tags: html5, skype

Estoy tratando de agregar el botón web de Skype, cuando lo hago todo va bien, pero este se posiciona al final de la web y crea un espacio vacio que va por dejabo del footer (aunque ponga el div que me da Skype en cualquier parte de la página).

Quiero quitar ese espacio que crea al final sin dejar de poner el botón en la parte derecha inferior de mi página.

[image: Aquí se puede apreciar ese espacio en blanco que crea el botón]

el div que me da Skype es este:

```
<div class="skype-button bubble" data-bot-id="YOUR_BOT_ID"></div>
```

No obstante haciendo mas pruebas, me di cuenta de que el script que me da Skype es el causante de dicho vacio, es este:

```
<script src="https://swc.cdn.skype.com/sdk/v1/sdk.min.js"></script>
```

No le he dado CSS a este botón porque este ya está hecho, solo lo agregué al HTML tal y como dice en la descripción de: https://dev.skype.com/webcontrol.

Comment: agrega por favor el código css o el div que te fue provisto para que la comunidad sepa como o por donde empezar a orientarte

Answer (score 0):

Al div que te dio Skype, agregale la propiedad style="float:right".

```
<div style="float:right"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que lo que quieres hacer es crear un botón flotante, y poder gestionar los márgenes que dejas.

Es difícil entender a lo que te refieres sin publicar tu código CSS y HTML, pero de todas maneras prueba lo siguiente:

En el código CSS añade lo siguiente al estilo de tu botón:

```
.botonSkype{  
  position:fixed;
  margin-right:16px;
  margin-bottom:16px;  
}
```

Si no te sirve, muestra el código para que te podamos ayudar.

¡Un saludo!